# predictor-corrector method and stability

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

A predictor-corrector method for the approximate solution of $y'=f(t,y)$ uses
\begin{equation} y_{n+1}-y_{n}=hf_{n}     \tag P
\end{equation}
as predictor and
\begin{equation} y_{n+1}-y_{n}=\frac{h}{2}(f_{n+1}+f_{n})     \tag C
\end{equation}
IF $(P)$ and $(C)$ are used in PECE mode on the vector problem
\begin{equation} \frac{du}{dt}=u
\end{equation}
 \begin{equation} \frac{dv}{dt}=-10u-11v+cos(2\pi t)
\end{equation}
with $u(0)$,$v(0)$ given, find the largest constant $\gamma >0$ for which the scheme is stable in the sense of Von Neumann (Fourier series stability and frequency) whenever $0<\gamma<0$. Give full details of your argument.

=>
I haven't try very well because its really difficult question for me.
I was thinking 
\begin{equation} y_{n+1}=y_{n}+hf_{n}     \tag P
\end{equation}
as predictor and
\begin{equation} y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\frac{h}{2}(f_{n+1}+f_{n})     \tag C
\end{equation}
iam trying to get transition matrix but these condition
\begin{equation} \frac{du}{dt}=u
\end{equation}
 \begin{equation} \frac{dv}{dt}=-10u-11v+cos(2\pi t)
\end{equation}
 i don't know how and where to use. 
please help me.

Comment: Your corrector expression isn't quite right. Either it should be $\hat y_{n+1}$ determined by the predictor and then $y_{n+1}-\hat y_{n+1}$ determined by the corrector, or the bracketed term in the corrector should be $f_{n+1}+f_n$.

Comment: you are correct. it is indeed $f_{n+1}+f_{n}$. Can you please help me little bit more with some caculation

Comment: I am unclear on what you mean by "transition matrix", as I'm fairly certain that's a stochastic term.

Comment: sorry i just to set $2 by 2$ matrix so i can diagonalise the matrix.